# Navegador falar para usuário apertar tecla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou fazendo um projeto voltado para pessoa cegas, queria saber se existe algum modo de fazer o navegador falar por voz "Aperte a tecla ENTER para falar", estou usando o SpeechRecognition para reconhecer a falar do usuário, mas não encontrei em nenhum local que pesquisei uma forma de fazer o navegador falar.

Comment: Eu tb havia começado um projeto semelhante e eu usava as vozes do google em formato mp3, mas abandonei o projeto porque as vozes não ficaram muito boas. :/ Mas vc pode usar a tag <audio> para fazer isso se vc tiver os mp3 com as vozes.

Comment: Precisa verificar se é compatível com todos os browsers, mas tem uma API para sintetização de voz (*text to speech*): [Web Speech API - Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API) e [Introduction to the Speech](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk-Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na mesma api 'Web Speech API' que esta usando "Speech recognition" há também o "Speech synthesis",

Uma boa leitura pode ser obtida em: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API](http://Web%20Speech%20API)

Como Exemplo de implementação:

```js
function falar(texto){
  var text  = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
      text.lang = "pt-BR";
      text.text = texto;
    
        //voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
      text['voiceURI'] = 'Google português do Brasil'; //discovered after dumping getVoices()
      text.lang = "pt-BR";
      text['localService'] = true;
      
  speechSynthesis.speak(text);
}

falar("Aperte a tecla Enter para falar");
```